# Select rows from a particular row to latest row if that particular row type exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to achieve these two requirements using a **single query**. Currently I'm using 2 queries in the program and use C# to do the process part something like this.

Pseudocode

```
select top 1 id from table where type=b
if result.row.count > 0 {var typeBid = row["id"]}
select * from table where id >= {typeBid}
else
select * from table
```

Req1: If there is records exist with type=b, Result should be latest row with type=b  and all other rows added after.

Table

```
--------------------
id  type    date
--------------------
1   b   2021-10-15
2   a   2021-11-16
3   b   2021-11-19
4   a   2021-12-02
5   c   2021-12-12
6   a   2021-12-16
```

Result

```
--------------------
id  type    date
--------------------
3   b   2021-11-19
4   a   2021-12-02
5   c   2021-12-12
6   a   2021-12-16
```

Req2: There is NO record exist with type=b. Query should select all the records in the table

Table

```
---------------------
id  type    date
---------------------
1   a   2021-10-15
2   a   2021-11-16
3   a   2021-11-19
4   a   2021-12-02
5   c   2021-12-12
6   a   2021-12-16
```

Result

```
--------------------
id  type    date
--------------------
1   a   2021-10-15
2   a   2021-11-16
3   a   2021-11-19
4   a   2021-12-02
5   c   2021-12-12
6   a   2021-12-16
```

Comment: Put your `if` [inside](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) your SQL?

Comment: @GSerg is it a decent way to do that?

Comment: What would be the result if there also was a row (7, d, 2021-11-19), i.e. having the same date as the latest b row?

Comment: @jarlh don't care about the date or types other than `b`. In above both requirement `7, d, 2021-11-19` will be in the result.

Answer (score 1):

```
with max_b_date as (select max(date) as date
                    from table1 where type = 'b')
select t1.*
from table1 t1
cross join max_b_date 
where t1.date >= max_b_date.date
   or max_b_date.date is null
```

(`table` is a SQL reserved word, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words, so I used `table1` as table name instead.)

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bd05543a9712e27f01528708f10b209f

Comment: This works perfectly! btw, just carious how do you know `max_b_date.date is null` when `type=b` not available? does `WITH common_table_expression` always set to null when select query not return any data?

Comment: Exactly, max_b_date.date will be null when there's no b in the table.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this(It's somewhat deep but might you exact looking for)

```
select ab.* from 
    ((select top 1 id, type, date from test where type = 'b' order by id desc)
    union 
    select * from test where type != 'b') as ab 
where ab.id >= (select COALESCE((select top 1 id from test where type = 'b' order by id desc), 0))
order by ab.id;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=739eb6bfee787e5079e616bbf4e933b1

Answer (score -1):

Looks Like you can use an `OR` condition here

```
SELECT  
    *
    FROM
    (
        SELECT  
            *,
            BCount = COUNT(CASE type WHEN 'B' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)-- to get the Count of Records with Type b.
            FROM Table
    )Q
    WHERE 
    (
        BCount > 0 AND id >= (select top 1 id from table where type=b)-- if there are Row's with Type b then select Req#1
    )
    OR
    (
        BCount = 0 -- if THere are no rows with Type B select All
    )
```